# CakePHP failed to load jquery

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp-2.x

I am trying to include a jquery file inside my CakePHP project. However, in console i get this error:

> `"ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".`

Physical file is located as it should be, in \app\webroot\js. It also fails to load it if I try from the internet. Here are relevant pieces of code:

**Layouts/default.ctp**

```
<?php
$cakeDescription = __d('cake_dev', 'CakePHP: the rapid development php framework');
$cakeVersion = __d('cake_dev', 'CakePHP %s', Configure::version())
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
<title>
    <?php echo $cakeDescription ?>:
    <?php echo $this->fetch('title'); ?>
</title>
<?php
echo $this->Html->meta('icon');

echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
echo $this->Html->css('kickstart');
echo $this->Html->css('style');

echo $this->fetch('meta');
echo $this->fetch('css');
echo $this->fetch('script');

echo $this->Html->script('kickstart.js');

echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min');
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<?php echo $this->Flash->render(); ?>
<div class="grid">

    <!-- ===================================== END HEADER ===================================== -->

    <div class="col_12">
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
    </div>

</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that your `kickstart.js` file, and/or something in your `script` block references jQuery, but jQuery isn't yet loaded at that time. If so, the fix is simply to make sure that `jquery.min` comes before those pieces in your layout.

Comment: Thanks! All I did is moved it upper in lines from kickstart.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically somethinkg in kickstart.js was blocking jquery.min file. All I did was moved jquery a line above kickstart.js so it shall be processed before kickstart.js file.